# Detecting DKIM and DMARC settings

Tags: php, dkim, dmarc

I am trying to build a tool to check for the presence of `DKIM` and `DMARC` for a particular domain. The issue with detecting `DKIM` is that I cannot check the `TXT` record of the domain because the `DKIM` selector is unknown to me as this is a query that will be run without recipient of an email from that sender. I also cannot find useful information on grabbing `DMARC` policies via PHP either. I've been trying the last two days and all I've managed to nail is an `SPF` check.

Any help provided would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said you're not going to be able to grab the DKIM record, because you won't know what the selector is, unless you have a signed email from that domain.

However, the DMARC check is just like the SPF Check.  You're looking for a TXT record under `_dmarc.exampledomain.com` that starts with `v=DMARC1`

When you do SPF you're looking for a TXT record under `EXAMPLEDOMAIN.COM` that starts with `v=spf1`, It's pretty much the same the same you just need to add the `_dmarc.` in from of the domain name before you do the lookup.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing that out! In regards to DKIM, I was simply hoping there would be some sort of work around such as a finite set of possible selectors or something along those lines.

Comment: You can create your own selector name, a lot of places choose something like `secure', `dkim`, `selecter` or `default`. But it can be anything.

Comment: Can you please send the code. how to get **DKIM and DMARC** records. I have tried this but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

> @Brijesh Tanwar - Can you please send the code. how to get DKIM and DMARC records. I have tried this but it's not working for me.

To check DMARC

```
$result = dns_get_record("_dmarc.yourdomain.com",DNS_TXT);
print_r($result);
```

To check SPF

```
$result = dns_get_record("yourdomain.com",DNS_TXT);
print_r($result);
```

To check DKIM (if you know the selector)

```
$result = dns_get_record("selector._domainkey.yourdomain.com.",DNS_TXT);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: if you just want the TXT value just type `echo $result[0]["txt"];`